# Comparing cell values to each column's average

Tags: loops, excel, vba

I'm trying to prepare a code in vba for excel. For each month there is a list of values, each month is listed in a separate column, multiple values are listed below each month.

What I wanted to do is change the color of each cell which value is 4 times smaller than the month's average. So far my code looks like this, each average is calculated like I wanted it, but i can't seem to figure out how to get it to compare the cells only to one column's average, not to all of them consecutively - like it does now.

```
Sub MonthAverage()
    Dim Data As Variant
    Set Data = Selection
    Dim rows As Integer
    Dim columns As Integer

    rows = Data.rows.Count
    columns = Data.columns.Count

    Dim average As Double

    For j = 1 To columns
        average = 0#

        For i = 1 To rows
            average = average + Data.Cells(i, j)
        Next

        average = average / rows

        For Each cell In Data.Cells
            If cell.Value <= average / 4 Then cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        Next

        MsgBox average 'just to make sure I got the averages correctly
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: My 2-cent a bit off-topic. It is typically what pivot table are made for.

Comment: You could, and I'd say should, also just use Conditional Formatting and an Average formula. No VBA required.

Comment: I admit, it would be certainly faster and easier for me to do, however i was looking for a way to do it in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code to work on the `ActiveSheet` instead of the current `Selection`. This code loops through each column in the `ActiveSheet` and formats the color for each cell that is less than four times smaller than the average.

```
Sub MonthAverageV2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ThresholdVal As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim r As Integer

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    'Loop columns
    For i = 1 To ws.Cells(1, ws.columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        r = ws.Cells(ws.rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
        'Column average
        ThresholdVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.average(ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, i).Address & ":" & ws.Cells(r, i).Address)) * 0.25
        Debug.Print ThresholdVal
        'Loop rows
        For j = 2 To r
            If ws.Cells(j, i).Value < ThresholdVal Then
                ws.Cells(j, i).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Also, I make use of `Application.WorksheetFunction.average` to calculate the average for each column.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, could this be made to work if i have names listed in the lefmost column of the table in excel? (it's basically a table of results, where each name has one value per month) As you can see, I am not very fluent in coding, could you also tell me if it would be even possible to get it to work using the method i applied or was it just not the right choice alltogether?

Comment: Ah, I think I got the first part, it would be for i=2

Comment: Yes if you want to skip the first column just run the loop from `i=2`.